# Launch firefox with selenium including firefox add-ons

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Python 3.x and Selenium, all updated.  Trying to launch firefox with Selenium with my add-ons intact.  Even relevant answer on Stackoverflow I have tried, nothing works.  Any Selenium wizards out there?

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('<path to my one firefox profile which     includes add-ons at launch')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='<path to geckodriver>', firefox_profile=fp)
```

I am expecting Selenium to launch Firefox with my add-ons intact.  Specifically, I want the random user agent switcher add on to function as normal, i.e. change user agent periodically.

Comment: I finally found the answer!  To save hours, here it is.  I added this line to the Selenium features at the top of my Python Code.     driver.install_addon(',path to firefox extension file')

Comment: your comment isn't an answer.  It doesn't show how to launch a browser with existing user add-ons.  Instead, it installs an extension into a blank profile.  It's a good solution to your problem, but not an answer to what you asked.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.  The entire line of code, which adds an extension into the default profile, does, in fact, load firefox with that add-on working and available.

Comment: right.. but that's not what you asked ("launch firefox with Selenium with my add-ons intact")

Answer (score 1):

It changes your layout a bit. But after struggling with `Selenium` for quite a while, the following implementation of `WebDriver` really helped me with setting attributes like `options` and `profile`.

```
from selenium import webdriver

# tag options field
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()  
# disable push/popups 
options.set_preference("dom.push.enabled", False)  

# tag profile option
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile() 
# what's the profile then (normally imported from separate infos.py)
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) \
              AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML,like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16"
# adjust profile to reflect user_agent profile
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", user_agent)

# set driver with options 
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, firefox_profile=profile)
```

Glad to read you were able to find an answer. Hope this was helpful or/and can be of use in the future. Have a great day!